# Find the circle best fit to points as well as its least squares error

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the center and radius of a circle best fit to the points $(3,3)$, $(3,7)$, $(9,1)$, and $(8,8)$.  Also compute its error

Mostly, I don't understand how to find the least squares error of circles.

Comment: Given a circle centered in $(x_0,t_0)$ and radius $r$, the error $e_1$ to a point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $e_1=\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}-r$.  For the least squares error, then have the square of each $e_i$ and sum them up.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Carlos' comment, each possible circle of centre $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r$ generates a sum of squared deviations
$$S(x_0,y_0,r)=\sum_{i=1}^4\left|\sqrt{(x_i-x_0)^2+(y_i-y_0)^2}-r\right|^2=\sum_{i=1}^4\left(\sqrt{(x_i-x_0)^2+(y_i-y_0)^2}-r\right)^2.$$

You see points $(x_0,y_0,r)\in\mathbb{R^2}\times \mathbb{R}_+$ correspond bijectively with circles so minimising $S(x_0,y_0,r)$ is the same as finding the best circle in the *least squares* sense.

Do you know how to find the minimum of a function? The sum is over the four points $\{x_i,y_i\}=\{(3,3),(3,7),(9,1),(8,8)\}$.